# What exactly should be added in the b2cscopes array in msal.service file for Angular app?

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to use Azure AD B2C authentication for my Angular app which uses ASP.NET core web api in the backend. I created a new Azure AD B2C tenant and registered both angular and web api applications with the tenant.

The configurations for the web api application registered with the tenant are shown in the below image.

[image]

I added the required msal code in my Angular app. In the msal.service.ts file, there is a b2cscopes array where I added the App ID URI shown in the above picture which is 'https://PCEFTPOSB2CTesting.onmicrosoft.com/api/'. When I run the application it fails inside the 'login' function shown in the below picture. The error is 
**Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at MSALService.login (msal.service.ts:26)**

[image]

I am not sure what to add in the b2cscopes array. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated Answer:

The b2cscopes should be the Published scopes in your Application which registered in Azure AD B2C.

Here is my application published scopes :

[image]

So, the b2cScopes value should be like this:

```
 b2cScopes: ["<your App ID URI>/<SCOPE>"]
```

Example:

```
b2cScopes: ["https://mydomian.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read"]
```

Go to Azure portal to check the Publish scopes of your application and then add  `<SCOPE>` in the end of your b2cscopes.

Also , according to your error, you need to know how to define `login` in `msal.service.ts`. Here is a sample :

```
public login(): void {
   var _this = this;
    this.clientApplication.loginPopup(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (idToken: any) {
        _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
            function (accessToken: any) {
                _this.access_token = accessToken;
            }, function (error: any) {
                _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
                    function (accessToken: any) {
                        _this.access_token = accessToken;
                    }, function (error: any) {
                        bootbox.alert("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
                    });
            })
    }, function (error: any) {
        bootbox.alert("Error during login:\n" + error);
    });
}
```

See more details about this sample in [**this link**](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular2.4-spa/blob/master/src/app/services/msal.service.ts).

Comment: Hi. As you mentioned, I added Scope as 'test' and Description as 'read' and then added b2cscopes array as ["https://<mydomainnamehere>.onmicrosoft.com/testapi/test.read"] but I am still having the same issue. Is it anything to do with App ID URI under Properties tab? For my app it is https://<mydomainnamehere>.onmicrosoft.com/api

Comment: Yes , you got it. It should be `https://<mydomainnamehere>.onmicrosoft.com/api /test.read`

Comment: Sorry for my unclear, you just need to add `test.read` after the AppID URI  .The example in my answer is under my App ID URI.

Comment: I added as you mentioned above but still having the same issue. The error is 
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at MSALService.login

Comment: I tried this login function before and also now again but when I do this and run the app, it says loading and remains frozen in the browser without showing any error. I run the app on 'http://localhost:4200/' and my web api runs on 'http://localhost:53040/' . Both apps use http instead of https. Is that a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163024/discussion-between-suvenk-and-wayne-yang-msft).

Comment: Hi @suvenk. I think yuu should use the same port ,not different ports. Also. I believe we have resolve the old issue. If this new issue need to be deep engaged, you'd better open a new question . I think we will handle it. Tha

Comment: That doesn’t seem right to me.  I think it is supposed to be just scope not scope.desc.  In the B2C examples the scope is ‘demo.read’

Comment: Hi Wayne - please re-review your answer.  `b2cScopes: ["<your App ID URI>/<SCOPE.DESCRIPTION>"]` is incorrect.  The desc is not used when requesting tokens to my knowledge.

Comment: Hi, @spottedmahn . Sorry for my late reply. You're right. Though it worked in my test, but is not a correct way. We should just use the scope value . NOT scope. description.  Thank you again. It's my fault. I have updated the answer.